# What are the advantages of using OSGi at target side in a Remote Software Provisioning System?

Tags: apache, osgi, target, provisioning

I am developing a Remote Software Provisioning system that should be able to handle all deployment, installation, un-installation and upgrades of software components. Software can be in any language (java, .net, c/c++ etc) and target side can be PC, embedded systems and smart phones.

I have found Apache ACE as good candidate for developing this system.

I want to know if there is any advantage/necessity of using OSGi at target side as Apache ACE can do software provisioning to non-OSGi targets as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've given some examples in the other question you asked:

[What are the non-osgi targets with which Apache ACE can work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682198/what-are-the-non-osgi-targets-with-which-apache-ace-can-work/)

You can write your own management agent that talks to the ACE server and installs artifacts. There actually are a couple of places where you could hook in your own code and protocol. Is there a concrete language/environment you're thinking of using, or are you just exploring the possibilities right now?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

We are working to find solutions to provision software on embedded devices e.g. upgrade firmware . So, our focus is on C/C++. We found Apache Celix as an OSGi implementation for C that we can use at target side but it is currently in early stage.

Comment: That's definitely true. Celix, as an open source project, is always looking for contributors, so if you've tried it, providing some feedback about your experience on their mailing list would be great. There you might also find more information about how ACE and Celix can interoperate.

Answer (score 2):

Having a modular framework like OSGi at the client side is a huge advantage when doing remote management, because it gives you much insight into what's happening inside - installed bundles, dependencies, states of the bundles, available services etc. This helps a lot when you have to solve a problem remotely. Another advantage is that OSGi basically forces programmers to develop proper modular and dynamic systems, which makes (remote) updating much easier.

So, if you have to decide now what language and framework to use for the client side, I strongly recommend OSGi for the embedded and mobile clients. For the PCs (I guess you mean desktop PCs?) this is probably not the best choice - it depends a lot what you want to achieve there. If you want to install MS Office remotely OSGi won't bring you forward ;)

However, if you already have existing programs at the client side and are discussing whether to convert them to OSGi, I would recommend to investigate some time first to see whether they can be converted easily. Some software packages could give you a lot of trouble converting to OSGi, not because OSGi is complex, but because the program itself is not modular and has a lot of assumptions about the static nature of the environment (e.g. nothing ever disappears, parts of the system never get updated etc.).  The irony in the matter is that these are exactly the programs which will give you most trouble later anyway no matter which remote provisioning system you chose.

If you have OSGi at some of the targets be sure to use a remote provisioning system which gives you access to the full OSGi functionality and not only the most basic and simple install and update functions. I haven't yet used Apache ACE, but I have experience with another provisioning system - [mPower Remote Manager](http://www.prosyst.com/index.php/de/html/content/98/Other-FOU-|-Products-|-Remote-Management-Server/). Here are some [snapshots from the documentation](http://dz.prosyst.com/pdoc/mPRM/um/system/user/mconsole_user.html) which can give you a feeling what is possible with OSGi as a base - you can draw your own conclusions whether it will be useful for your case or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the advantages of OSGi haven't changed, so for that I can refer you to [the standard page](http://www.osgi.org/About/WhyOSGi).

To be a bit more constructive, I'll read the question as 'Should I bother converting my application to OSGi, as it is not necessary for ACE?'

I think that depends on what 'kind' of updating mechanism you're after. If you have a monolithical application (at least from the provisioning perspective) which you deploy and update only as a whole (Like an iOS app) then there isn't much to gain *for provisioning purposes* by using OSGi.

For the rest I can tell you the same as I tell anybody else: Converting an application to OSGi isn't hard, but modularizing code can be a nightmare, but something you'll need to face at some point, OSGi or not. If your code is modularized already, using OSGi should be a piece of cake.